# How do I get the width inside of style inside of class of span?

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

[image: HTML screenshot]

I'm trying to get the result out so that I'll be able to get what's inside of "width: 100%" and only the number part. I'm using beautifulsoup python. and my code is here for getting it:

```
rating_data.append(e.select_one('.review-list__rating__active'))
```

but it keeps giving me the whole entire line which is

```
<span class="review-list__rating__active" style="width: 100%">
```

above result.
I'm trying to get the value inside of the width. is that any possible using beautifulsoup, python? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The [`cssutils`](https://pypi.org/project/cssutils/) library can help with this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cssutils

html = """<span class="review-list__rating__active" style="width: 100%"></span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
span_style = soup.select_one('.review-list__rating__active')['style']
style = cssutils.parseStyle(span_style)

print(style.width)
```

This displays:

```
100%
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of an attribute use `get()`:

```
e.select_one('.review-list__rating__active').get('style')
```

If there is only one style you could use `split()` to get the value:

```
e.select_one('.review-list__rating__active').get('style').split(':')[-1]
```

If there are multiple you have to iterate:

```
for s in e.select_one('.review-list__rating__active').get('style').split(';'):
    if 'with' in s:
        print(s.split(':')[-1])
```

Another alternativ would be to use `regex`.